# mod_rewrite .htaccess $_GET[] request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make friendly urls.

`www.site.com/index.php?view=newest` to `www.site.com/newest`

My current .htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^newest ./index.php?view=newest
```

It works, but you can go to `www.site.com/newest/laksdjf` or `www.site.com/newestskdf` (with page errors)

I'm also trying this so it works for multiple $_GET[] requests.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?view=$1
```

How can I modify these so it only works for `www.site.com/newest` or `www.site.com/newest/`?

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^newest/?$ ./index.php?view=newest
```